# How do I add a comma, then and in an orderly way in Python?

Tags: python

I am making a "wordfinder" kind of script, where you can type in a word and it returns the positions the word was found in. However, if the word occurs more that once, I don't want it to say

***This word occurs in positions(s): 3 and 4 and 5...***

I want it to say:

***This word occurs in position(s): 3, 4 and 5...***

At the moment, it returns, if there are two positions in which the word occurs:

***This word occurs in position(s): 3 and 4 and...***

This is my code so far:

```
 sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"

List=[]

for i in sentence.split(" "):
    List.append(i)

print(sentence)

position = "Your word is found in position(s): "

keyword = input("Please enter a word you want to find the position of. ").upper()

times=0

for i in range (len(List)):
    if keyword in List[i]:
        i=i+1
        times=times+1
        found=str(i)
        position = position + found + " and "

if times==0:
    print("The word was not found.")
else:       
    print(position)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would record the positions you found the string during the loop, and format them afterwards.

Say you make `found` a list of locations, and in the loop you would do `found.append(str(i))`, then after the loop is done, something like this:

```
if len(found) == 1:
    position += "{}".format(found[0])
else:
    # This will put a comma between everything except the last entry
    position += ", ".join(found[0:-1])
    # Then we add the last entry
    position += " and {}".format(found[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Python strings have a very nice join function that can help adding separators between list items. Since you want to add an "and" before the last item, you can join every item except the last one using join and add the " add " before adding the last one...

Combined this makes:

```
if not List:
    print("The word was not found.")
else:
    msg = "Your word is found in position(s): "
    if len(List) >  1:
        msg = msg + ', '.join([str(i) for i in List[:-1]]) + ' and '
    print(msg + str(List[-1]))
```

However, it is a bit of a shame that you are still using `position(s)` Instead you could use:

```
if not List:
    print("The word was not found.")
else:
    if len(List) >  1:
        print("Your word is found in positions:", ', '.join([str(i) for i in List[:-1]]), 'and ', str(List[-1]))
    else:
        print("Your word is found in position:", str(List[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a list
- Store all positions where you find the word.
- Create a new `result` string.
- Iterate over list
- Append each word to the `result` string.
- If you see `n - 1`th word, append `and`, otherwise append `,`. If you are processing `n`th word, don't append anything.
- finally, print result string.

This is general programming approach. I'm pretty sure that, there would be an elegant python solution.

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
words = sentence.split(' ')

positions = []
print (sentence)
keyword = raw_input("Please enter a word you want to find the position of. ").upper()

i = 0
for i in range(len(words)):
  if keyword in words[i]:
    positions.append(i)

if len(positions):
  result = ''

  n = len(positions)

  i = 0
  while i < n:
    result += str(positions[i])
    if i == n - 2:
      result += ' and '
    elif i < n - 2:
      result += ', '
    i += 1
  print(result)

else:       
  print("The word was not found.")
```

Comment: This is extremely un-Pythonic.